# Polynomials $\&$ Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, companion-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Assume $A$ is a matrix of order $n$.  We know that the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$ is obtained as follows
$$
P(x)=\det (A-x\,I)\, .
$$

Where $I$ is an identity matrix of order $n$. What about inverse?  For a given polynomial 
like $P(x)$, Is there an efficient method to find a 
matrix like $A$ where the  characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$ be the polynomial $P(x)$.

I know that the number of matrices that have the same characteristic polynomials  are uncountable. Because, If 
we assume that all entries of matrix $A$ be indeterminates then the number of variables in 
the equation 
$$
\det (A-x\,I)=P(x)
$$
 are more than equations. Thanks for any suggestion.

**Edit:**

My motivation of this question is that if $A$ be a non-derogatory matrix (in other words, its minimal and characteristic polynomials coincide) then Frobenius normal form of matrix $A$ is a companion matrix. Now, If we have a companion matrix like $C$, how to find a matrix like $A$, such that the companion matrix $C$ be the Frobenius normal form of matrix $A$.

The user @Jack answered the obviously solution of my original question and because of this I edit my question.

Comment: Changing your question in a fundamental way after you saw an answer is not a good idea in this site. Since in that way, you would essentially make an existence answer meaningless. You could instead add *comment* to your question or to the answer. Or alternatively, add an line to your original post for what you might want to ask further.

Comment: You right, I ask my original question as a edit. I know what you mean.

Comment: Dear @Jack, Thanks for your notification.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. What you are looking for is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Comment: Thanks but i mean the matrix except  companion matrix. I edit my question by your tip.

Comment: What is the point for such change? *Any* similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. Thus if you don't like the "companion matrix", then you can just do a similar transform to it.

Comment: this question is related to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256638/the-nth-power-of-a-matrix-by-companion-matrix). I will ask my original Question in next comment

Comment: Dear @Jack, I like the companion matrix, becuse I have been working in application of companion matrix in coding theory for one year.